# EmailComposer Cordova Plugin not working in ios 6.0

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins

I am working with cordova2.2.0 with jquery mobile for iphone. I am using EmailComposer  plugin, but problem is that, it is working in simulator 5.0 but not working in simulator 5.1 and later and devices.

I have done all coding for plugin process. This function called on click event. Please help me.

```
function emailComposer(){
   window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("Subject","PlainTextBody", "recipient,recipient", "ccRecipient", "bccRecipient",false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while I also fail to run it, it seems that you should replace string parameters with array parameters for recipients etc. I've seen this reply in another thread.